# Angular not updating UI on state change

Tags: angular

EDIT: Voting to close for a couple reasons. For one, I think this is basically a dupe. For two, I'm pretty confident that my whole situation is so contrived as to make the solution possibly useless to me. I'm going to look into the data model and see how that is supposed to work. Hopefully this stuff comes a bit more clear once I have an understanding there.

Original:

I'm very new to Angular (though I have experience in JavaScript, Java, etc), and I feel like I'm misunderstanding a core concept here.

I've created a Component "TestComponent" whose class is being exported, which has a field "message". The HTML for that component is set to display the value of "message", and this works. I've also added a setter function to the TestComponent class, "setMessage()", which takes a String, and updates the message.

Meanwhile, in the Root App Component, I've added a constructor to its class which instantiates(? Maybe this is the issue. Are components singletons? Is there a way to get a reference to an already-existing component?) a new TestComponent and calls the setter to update the message.

I'd expect to see that the message is now the overridden message, but instead it remains the default message. Here's a StackBlitz explaining what I'm talking about

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j6x2km?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Any help here is greatly appreciated. If I can clarify anything, I will (frankly I know I lack the Angular vocab/understanding to properly explain the issue, so I'll do my best).

Comment: Components are not singletons so the `<app-test>` instance in your main component's template is not the same instance as the one you're manually newing up in the main component's code-behind. [N.F.'s anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77857148/14956277) correctly binds a variable in the main component's code-behind to the instance of your test component in the main component's template.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to pass values to child components is to use `@Input()` and add argument to `<app-test>`.

**main.ts**

```
     :
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <app-test [message]=message></app-test>
  `,
     :
export class App {
  message: string = '';

  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Overwritten message';
  }
```

**testcomponent.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() message: String = 'Default Message';

  setMessage(newMessage: String) {
    this.message = newMessage;
  }
}
```

I have forked your stackblitz, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-yyj8v8?file=src%2Ftestcomponent%2Ftestcomponent.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts).